# Define instance of a typeclass for any kind of number

Tags: haskell

everyone. I am new to Haskell. I would like to define a instance of typeclass that suitable for any kind of number. Take a example, let me write a simple typeclass:

```hs
class YesNo a where
    yesno :: a -> Bool
```

Basically, the `yesno` function mimics JavaScript's  boolean checking behaviour. If you give it a "truly" value, it will return `True`, otherwise it will return `False`. Here are some examples to use it:

```hs
yesno "3" -- True
yesno 3.0 -- True
yesno 0 -- False
yesno ""  -- False
yesno [] -- False
```

There is a problem that, there are several types to represent different number in Haskell: `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`... Although I can write a single `yesno` function for these types, I have to define instances for them respectively.

```
class YesNo a where
    yesno :: a -> Bool

instance YesNo Integer where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True

instance YesNo Int where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True

instance YesNo Float where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True

instance YesNo Double where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True
```

While it works, it looks very cumbersome and boring to write. I was wondering if there is a more concise way to finish this, something like:

```hs
instance YesNo Integer where
instance YesNo Int where
instance YesNo Float where
instance YesNo Double where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True
```

The code doesn't comply to Haskell's syntax, obviously. I also tried to add a type constraint for the instance.

```
instance (Num a) => YesNo a where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True
```

I wished it would have worked, but it didn't, and following error was shown in GHCi. It seems the type of a instance must be concrete, and a typeclass is not acceptable.

```
TypeClass.hs:39:21: error:
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘YesNo a’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘YesNo a’
```

Comment: Did you try what the compiler suggests and enable `FlexibleInstances`? You can do that by putting `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` at the top of the file.

Comment: Generally agree with @RobinZigmond that `-XFlexibleInstances` is completely unproblematic, however in this case it just kicks the stone down the road: first you'll also need `-XUndecidableInstances` (still ok), and then once you have `instance (Num a) => YesNo a` working all _other_ instances like `instance YesNo Bool` will break, because they're [_overlapping_](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap) as far as the language knows. Again, GHC does have features to allow overlapping instances, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 4):

If you control the class declaration, you can do this for a single constraint this way:

```
{-# Language DefaultSignatures #-}
class YesNo a where
    yesno :: a -> Bool
    default yesno :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True

instance YesNo Integer
instance YesNo Int
instance YesNo Float
instance YesNo Double
```

If you don't control the class declaration, or you want to have two different kinds of defaults, then the best you can do is something like this:

```
class YesNo a where
    yesno :: a -> Bool

yesnoNum :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
yesnoNum 0 = False
yesnoNum _ = True

yesnoMonoid :: (Eq a, Monoid a) => a -> Bool
yesnoMonoid a = mempty /= a

instance YesNo Integer where yesno = yesnoNum
instance YesNo Int     where yesno = yesnoNum
instance YesNo Float   where yesno = yesnoNum
instance YesNo Double  where yesno = yesnoNum
instance Eq a => YesNo [a] where yesno = yesnoMonoid -- just an example, use null and no Eq constraint in real code
```